# How to figure out what JARs are in Hadoop classpath fin HDP2.5 sandbox?

Tags: hadoop, classpath, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

How to figure out what JARs are in Hadoop classpath?
I'm using Hortonworks 2.5 sandbox and want to run my custom application using already present im sandbox Hadoop JARs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a command `hadoop classpath` that does exactly you need.
Please refer here for more details:
[https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/27780/where-exactly-classpaths-for-hadoop-are-present-in.html](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Where-exactly-classpaths-for-hadoop-are-present-in/m-p/170387)